# Why does TextEditingController() does not create a new controller

Tags: android, flutter, dart, matrix

There is an gridview built with use of an 2d array of `TextFields` so I can input matrix values manually. The function itself looks like this:

```
//controller for row count input field
final rowsController = TextEditingController();
//controller for columns count input field
final columnsController = TextEditingController();
//2d array of TextFields
late List<List<TextField?>> matrix;
//2d array of Controllers for textfields above
late List<List<TextEditingController?>> controllers;

void createMatrix() {
   setState(() {
    //matrix variable becomes 2d array of nulls with reqired length
    matrix = List<List<TextField?>>.filled(int.tryParse(rowsController.text)!,
      List<TextField?>.filled(int.tryParse(columnsController.text)!, null), growable: true);

    //controllers variable becomes 2d array of nulls with reqired length (same len as matrix 2d list)
    controllers = List<List<TextEditingController?>>.filled(int.tryParse(rowsController.text)!,
        List<TextEditingController?>.filled(int.tryParse(columnsController.text)!, null), growable: true);
    
    //both lists are being filled with data
    for (int row = 0; row < int.tryParse(rowsController.text)!; row++) {
      for (int item = 0; item < int.tryParse(columnsController.text)!; item++) {
        //controller[x,y] becomes NEW TextEditingController()
        controllers[row][item] = TextEditingController();
        //each TextField is created and linked with its controller from controllers list
        matrix[row][item] = TextField(controller: controllers[row][item]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The main problem is when I type something in created textfield, it duplicates same value into every item in column like this:

[image: duplication problem]

Looks like when TextField is created inside for loop it creates a reference instead of new object somehow but the builder of `TextEditingController()` but the description if this method tells the opposite.

UPD.
whole snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:number_inc_dec/number_inc_dec.dart';
import 'globals.dart';

class LabRab7 extends StatefulWidget {
  const LabRab7({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LabRab7> createState() => _LabRab7State();
}

class _LabRab7State extends State<LabRab7> {
  final rowsController = TextEditingController();
  final columnsController = TextEditingController();
  late List<List<TextField?>> matrix;
  late List<List<TextEditingController?>> controllers;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    rowsController.dispose();
    columnsController.dispose();
    for(var row in controllers){
      for(var item in row){
        item!.dispose();
      }
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    controllers = [
      [TextEditingController(), TextEditingController()],
      [TextEditingController(), TextEditingController()]
    ];
    matrix = [
      [
        TextField(controller: controllers[0][0]),
        TextField(controller: controllers[0][1])
      ],
      [
        TextField(controller: controllers[1][0]),
        TextField(controller: controllers[1][1])
      ]
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void createMatrix() {
       setState(() {

        matrix = List<List<TextField?>>.filled(int.tryParse(rowsController.text)!,
      List<TextField?>.filled(int.tryParse(columnsController.text)!, null), growable: true);

        controllers = List<List<TextEditingController?>>.filled(int.tryParse(rowsController.text)!,
        List<TextEditingController?>.filled(int.tryParse(columnsController.text)!, null), growable: true);
    
        for (int row = 0; row < int.tryParse(rowsController.text)!; row++) {
          for (int item = 0; item < int.tryParse(columnsController.text)!; item++) {
            controllers[row][item] = TextEditingController();
            matrix[row][item] = TextField(controller: controllers[row][item]);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        for(var row in controllers){
          for(var item in row){
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(item?.value.hashCode);
            }
          }
        }
        },),
        appBar: AppBar(
            leading: const BackButton(),
            backgroundColor: Notifiers.mainColor),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 150,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text("Rows count:"),
                NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement(
                  controller: rowsController,
                  min: 2,
                  max: 6,
                  initialValue: 2,
                  onIncrement: (_) {
                    createMatrix();
                  },
                  onDecrement: (_) {
                    createMatrix();
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const Text("Columns count:"),
                NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement(
                  controller: columnsController,
                  max: 6,
                  min: 2,
                  initialValue: 2,
                  onIncrement: (_) {
                    createMatrix();
                  },
                  onDecrement: (_) {
                    createMatrix();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: matrix.length * matrix[0].length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: matrix[0].length,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                int gridStateLength = matrix[0].length;
                int x, y = 0;
                x = (index / gridStateLength).floor();
                y = (index % gridStateLength);
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  child: GridTile(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: matrix[x][y],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Your function creates new objects. But your function to create Widget with textfields may be wrongly implemented, so it doesn't iterate correctly through the rows, so for every row in your function it passes the same row to Widget.

It's hard to answer to your problem because of lack of more code.

Comment: Added whole code